# Regex for excluding specific text

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex [This Regex problem](https://regex101.com/r/lMB8Bh/1)

All possible examples of the text are splitted by `###` in above link. All the text is not coming up at once instead only one block of text;that contains `description`,`unit price`, `number of units` and `total price in euros` . I want to extract the description and leave the unit price total price , number of units.

**First example text:**

```
55,000 M 24,40 1.342,00 EUR
3.1.020 / Ansatzpunkte für Kernbohrgerät / E3

58,000 ST 15,21 882,18 EUR #this line is not needed
```

**second example:**

```
​
incl. Umspannung des Trägers mit Rippenstreck-
​
metall, Putzdicke einlagig ca. 15 mm ,
​
Öffnungsgröße ca. 1,01 x 2,20 m
​
Wanddicke ca. 20 cm 1,00 Stck. 450,00 450,00 € #(this info is not needed 1,00 Stck. 450,00 450,00 €)
```

#

**Third example:**

```
DIN 18300, nach Ausbau des Pflasterbelages

profilgerecht lösen, laden, fördern u. lagern,

Aushubtiefe bis 0,30 m, Breite bis 1,50 mm,

Länge über 30 bis 35 m 2,00 m? 145,00 290,00 € #(this info is not needed 35 m 2,00 m? 145,00 290,00 €)
```

### what I want to do?

1. I want to get all the text **excluding** the currency like euro  for example`1.235,00 or 235,00 or 85,000`
2. The second thing I want to **exclude** is any digit (unit value)+ unit name.

**The uint name can be on of following:**
`H , st,stck, PSCH,Pschl, M M2, TO, LITE,ifdm,stück,Stück,Summe:,stWo,StMt,mMt, qm x,qmx, psch`
Note: it is possible that there is no space bweteen the digit and unit like 1,00stuck or 1Stk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
\b(?:\d+(?:[,.]\d+)*\s*)+(H|stck|st|PSCH|Pschl|mm ...abbreviations...  |qmx|gm|x|EUR|€)
```

and test it at https://regex101.com/r/yLNrZ5/1, where you can also see the explanation (right top corner) of this pattern.

---

**Important:** When you list the abbreviations and reserved words, list similar terms in the order from longer to shorter to ensure correct match - e.g. `m2|m` and not `m|m2`, or `stock|st` and not `st|stock`, etc.

Comment: I still did not managed to exclude the above match. Measure I do,t want these match but inverse.e.g result excluding these matches @ Ωmega

Comment: @Faisal - Please see *TEST STRING* shown at https://regex101.com/r/yLNrZ5/1 and for that input type in your desired output at https://justpaste.it/, save it and provide me with the link to access it.